# Error in FFmpeg's chromashift filter: "corrupted double-linked list"

Tags: linux, ffmpeg

I recently added an FFmpeg 4.1-static build (replacing the ppa 4.03-1 version) to my KDE Neon Linux in order to use the most recent video noise reduction filters. FFmpeg versions 4.03 and 4.1 reported, 'No such filter' for bm3d, dctdnoiz, dedot, fftdenoiz and chromashift. Using the git version only chromashift throws an error:

```
ffmpeg -y -loglevel debug -i Hi8_02.dv -vf chromashift=0:0:-1:-1 -c:v dnxhd -b:v 60M Hi8_02.mov

ffmpeg version N-47834-gb5e0a0fe3a-static https://johnvansickle.com/ffmpeg/  Copyright (c) 2000-2018 the FFmpeg developers
  built with gcc 6.3.0 (Debian 6.3.0-18+deb9u1) 20170516
  configuration: --enable-gpl --enable-version3 --enable-static --disable-debug --disable-ffplay --disable-indev=sndio --disable-outdev=sndio --cc=gcc-6 --enable-fontconfig --enable-frei0r --enable-gnutls --enable-gmp --enable-gray --enable-libaom --enable-libfribidi --enable-libass --enable-libvmaf --enable-libfreetype --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopencore-amrnb --enable-libopencore-amrwb --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-librubberband --enable-libsoxr --enable-libspeex --enable-libvorbis --enable-libopus --enable-libtheora --enable-libvidstab --enable-libvo-amrwbenc --enable-libvpx --enable-libwebp --enable-libx264 --enable-libx265 --enable-libxml2 --enable-libdav1d --enable-libxvid --enable-libzvbi --enable-libzimg
  libavutil      56. 25.100 / 56. 25.100
  libavcodec     58. 42.104 / 58. 42.104
  libavformat    58. 25.100 / 58. 25.100
  libavdevice    58.  6.101 / 58.  6.101
  libavfilter     7. 46.101 /  7. 46.101
  libswscale      5.  4.100 /  5.  4.100
  libswresample   3.  4.100 /  3.  4.100
  libpostproc    55.  4.100 / 55.  4.100
Splitting the commandline.
Reading option '-y' ... matched as option 'y' (overwrite output files) with argument '1'.
Reading option '-loglevel' ... matched as option 'loglevel' (set logging level) with argument 'debug'.
Reading option '-i' ... matched as input url with argument 'Hi8_02.dv'.
Reading option '-vf' ... matched as option 'vf' (set video filters) with argument 'chromashift=0:0:-1:-1'.
Reading option '-c:v' ... matched as option 'c' (codec name) with argument 'dnxhd'.
Reading option '-b:v' ... matched as option 'b' (video bitrate (please use -b:v)) with argument '60M'.
Reading option 'Hi8_02.mov' ... matched as output url.
Finished splitting the commandline.
Parsing a group of options: global .
Applying option y (overwrite output files) with argument 1.
Applying option loglevel (set logging level) with argument debug.
Successfully parsed a group of options.
Parsing a group of options: input url Hi8_02.dv.
Successfully parsed a group of options.
Opening an input file: Hi8_02.dv.
[NULL @ 0x601e700] Opening 'Hi8_02.dv' for reading
[file @ 0x601f000] Setting default whitelist 'file,crypto'
[dv @ 0x601e700] Format dv probed with size=2048 and score=75
[dv @ 0x601e700] Before avformat_find_stream_info() pos: 0 bytes read:32768 seeks:0 nb_streams:1
[dv @ 0x601e700] All info found
[dv @ 0x601e700] Estimating duration from bitrate, this may be inaccurate
[dv @ 0x601e700] After avformat_find_stream_info() pos: 120000 bytes read:120000 seeks:0 frames:2
Input #0, dv, from 'Hi8_02.dv':
  Metadata:
    timecode        : 02:01:40;13
  Duration: 01:42:32.05, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 28771 kb/s
    Stream #0:0, 1, 1001/30000: Video: dvvideo, 1 reference frame, yuv411p(topleft), 720x480 [SAR 8:9 DAR 4:3], 0/1, 25000 kb/s, 29.97 fps, 29.97 tbr, 29.97 tbn, 29.97 tbc
    Stream #0:1, 1, 1/30000: Audio: pcm_s16le, 48000 Hz, stereo, s16, 1536 kb/s
Successfully opened the file.
Parsing a group of options: output url Hi8_02.mov.
Applying option vf (set video filters) with argument chromashift=0:0:-1:-1.
Applying option c:v (codec name) with argument dnxhd.
Applying option b:v (video bitrate (please use -b:v)) with argument 60M.
Successfully parsed a group of options.
Opening an output file: Hi8_02.mov.                                                                                                                                                          
[file @ 0x6065280] Setting default whitelist 'file,crypto'                                                                                                                                   
Successfully opened the file.                                                                                                                                                                
detected 4 logical cores                                                                                                                                                                     
Stream mapping:
  Stream #0:0 -> #0:0 (dvvideo (native) -> dnxhd (native))
  Stream #0:1 -> #0:1 (pcm_s16le (native) -> aac (native))
Press [q] to stop, [?] for help
cur_dts is invalid (this is harmless if it occurs once at the start per stream)
[Parsed_chromashift_0 @ 0x612ff80] Setting 'cbh' to value '0'                                                                                                                                
[Parsed_chromashift_0 @ 0x612ff80] Setting 'cbv' to value '0'                                                                                                                                
[Parsed_chromashift_0 @ 0x612ff80] Setting 'crh' to value '-1'                                                                                                                               
[Parsed_chromashift_0 @ 0x612ff80] Setting 'crv' to value '-1'                                                                                                                               
[graph 0 input from stream 0:0 @ 0x61315c0] Setting 'video_size' to value '720x480'                                                                                                          
[graph 0 input from stream 0:0 @ 0x61315c0] Setting 'pix_fmt' to value '7'                                                                                                                   
[graph 0 input from stream 0:0 @ 0x61315c0] Setting 'time_base' to value '1001/30000'                                                                                                        
[graph 0 input from stream 0:0 @ 0x61315c0] Setting 'pixel_aspect' to value '8/9'                                                                                                            
[graph 0 input from stream 0:0 @ 0x61315c0] Setting 'sws_param' to value 'flags=2'                                                                                                           
[graph 0 input from stream 0:0 @ 0x61315c0] Setting 'frame_rate' to value '30000/1001'                                                                                                       
[graph 0 input from stream 0:0 @ 0x61315c0] w:720 h:480 pixfmt:yuv411p tb:1001/30000 fr:30000/1001 sar:8/9 sws_param:flags=2
[format @ 0x6131fc0] Setting 'pix_fmts' to value 'yuv422p|yuv422p10le|yuv444p10le|gbrp10le'
[auto_scaler_0 @ 0x6130200] Setting 'flags' to value 'bicubic'
[auto_scaler_0 @ 0x6130200] w:iw h:ih flags:'bicubic' interl:0
[format @ 0x6131fc0] auto-inserting filter 'auto_scaler_0' between the filter 'Parsed_chromashift_0' and the filter 'format'
[AVFilterGraph @ 0x60a6100] query_formats: 4 queried, 2 merged, 1 already done, 0 delayed
[auto_scaler_0 @ 0x6130200] picking yuv422p out of 4 ref:yuv411p alpha:0
[auto_scaler_0 @ 0x6130200] w:720 h:480 fmt:yuv411p sar:8/9 -> w:720 h:480 fmt:yuv422p sar:8/9 flags:0x4
*** Error in `ffmpeg': corrupted double-linked list: 0x0000000006131820 ***
======= Backtrace: =========
[0x3af8d27]
[0x3aff102]
[0x3aff48e]
[0x3afffd8]
[0x11697cf]
[0x813741]
[0x4bd4e4]
[0x498035]
[0x3acb0f3]
[0x3acb4b2]
[0x49aaea]
======= Memory map: ========
00400000-045a1000 r-xp 00000000 103:01 4461933                           /home/buddy/.local/bin/ffmpeg
047a0000-04947000 rw-p 041a0000 103:01 4461933                           /home/buddy/.local/bin/ffmpeg
04947000-053a4000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
05fef000-062ac000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0                                  [heap]
7f5cb0000000-7f5cb0091000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
7f5cb0091000-7f5cb4000000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0 
7f5cb4da0000-7f5cb4da1000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
7f5cb4da1000-7f5cb4da2000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0 
7f5cb4da2000-7f5cb55a2000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
7f5cb55a2000-7f5cb55a3000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0 
7f5cb55a3000-7f5cb5da3000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
7f5cb5da3000-7f5cb5da4000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0 
7f5cb5da4000-7f5cb65a4000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
7f5cb65a4000-7f5cb65a5000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0 
7f5cb65a5000-7f5cb6da5000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
7f5cb6da5000-7f5cb6da6000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0 
7f5cb6da6000-7f5cb75a6000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
7f5cb75a6000-7f5cb75a7000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0 
7f5cb75a7000-7f5cb7da7000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
7f5cb7da7000-7f5cb7da8000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0 
7f5cb7da8000-7f5cb85a8000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
7f5cb85a8000-7f5cb85a9000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0 
7f5cb85a9000-7f5cb8ec1000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
7ffec59a6000-7ffec59c7000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0                          [stack]
7ffec59de000-7ffec59e1000 r--p 00000000 00:00 0                          [vvar]
7ffec59e1000-7ffec59e3000 r-xp 00000000 00:00 0                          [vdso]
ffffffffff600000-ffffffffff601000 r-xp 00000000 00:00 0                  [vsyscall]
Aborted
```

Comment: Share full log. Can't reproduce here.

Comment: Fixed that bug just now.

Comment: FFmpeg 4.1 was in the ppa update this morning 2019-01-03. However, it still doesn't support the chromashift filter. Installed git-static 20190101 and that version chromashift=0:0:-1:1 properly corrected my old Hi8 video. Thankyou.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question because it's about a bug that was fixed.

Comment: Using Chromashift filter as advertised in FFmpeg Documentation reports, "No such filter," .... still. Only the static build works.